# Accidentally closed Python Console in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running python 3 on a Mac using PyCharm.

I accidentally closed the python console in PyCharm, and when I hit the Python Console tab it apparently just started a new instance and my previous console is gone, along with all the data/variables. Is there a way to recover the previous instance?

And for future reference, is there any way to prevent this from happening in the future? I find it kind of crazy I accidentally hit an "X" and everything is gone, without at least a warning or pop-up.

Comment: Hello and welcome! But please note this: It may be urgent for you, but it's certainly not urgent for us. Please don't use titles like that, it won't make you friends here on Stack Overflow, and makes it much _less_ likely that you receive assistance quickly! Read [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how you will be able to recover your work. But i think you should read the article i am attaching here to prevent it from happening in future. What I think is you should change the keymap of pycharm (the shortcuts) according to your preference.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html?keymap=primary_macos

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately this doesn't seem relevant to my problem. The "Close Window" "X" is built into the console. All it takes is one slip of a finger and it's gone.